# Redirect to current page after editing a record

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm listing 100 of records using a pagination in django. Each page contains 10 records. Suppose i'm on page 6 and selected a record to edit . After editing the record, successful url to redirect list view(which is first page). I need to stay the page where i pick the record to edit.

i tried using the {{ request.get_full_path }} which will show the current url. But i cant pass it to edit url, if i passed it will show in the url. I'm using Class Based View.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    now = datetime.now()
    self.object.updator = self.request.user.username
    self.object.date_updated = now 
    self.object.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Suppose my on 6th page, a picked a record to edit. After editing the record i need redirect back to 6th page. Please suggest me a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to edit link in object list template.

```html
<a href="{% url 'your_edit_urls_name' object.id %}?redirect_page={{ request.GET.page }}">edit</a>
```

And write `get_success_url` to your Edit class-based view

```py
def get_success_url(self):
        return '{0}?page={1}'.format(
            reverse_lazy('your_list_url_name'),
            self.request.GET.get('redirect_page'))
```

And return `get_success_url` in `form_valid` method:

```py
return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply Saeed, I tried the but i'm getting a exception. Exception Value: 
quote_from_bytes() expected bytes.

Comment: What is quote_from_bytes()?

Comment: Thank you saeed, i got it. please edit the answer.
return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url()), use parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `HttpResponseRedirect`if you want to keep your GET parameters. Use `return render(request, self.template, context)` or `return render(request, self.template)`.

Answer (score 0):

render your page after edit record and pass your get data as context in render request.

```
  def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        now = datetime.now()
        self.object.updator = self.request.user.username
        self.object.date_updated = now 
        self.object.save()
        return render(request, "you_html_page.html")
```